# Is there a counterexample $f(x,y)$ to "If the limit of $f$ along every path through a point equals to $L$, then $f$ has limit $L$ at that point"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(x,y) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a double variable real function and let $p = (x_0, y_0)$ be an interior point of $\mathrm{Dom}_f$. As I understand, $ \lim_{(x,y) \to p} f = L$ means that for every positive $\varepsilon$ there exists a positive $\delta$ such that $ f \big( B_{\delta}(p) \big) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(f)$. So if $ \lim_{(x,y) \to p} f = L$, one can deduce that along every path that passes through $p$, the limit of $f$ is equal to $L$: For a desired $\varepsilon$ there exists a suitable ball $B_\delta(p)$ and the intersection of the path with $B_\delta (p)$ I suppose would yield an open subset of the path containing $p$ with the desired property.

My question is about the converse: If $p$ is an interior point of the domain of some $f$, supposing that for a desired $\varepsilon$, every path through $p$ like $g$ yields a $ \delta_g $ (I think we can safely suppose $\delta_g$ is the greatest delta possible for $g$) such that $ f \big( B_{\delta_g}(p) \cap \mathrm{Im}(g) \big) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(f) $, can we deduce that there exists some $\delta^*$ for which $f\big(B_{\delta^*}(p) \big) \subset B_{\varepsilon}(f)$? I suspect that there might not exist such $\delta^*$, as we must have $\delta^* \leq \inf\{ \delta_g \mid \text{$g$ is a path through $p$} \}$ and this infimum might become zero. But neither I can think of an example $f$ nor I can prove that the infimum cannot be zero.

Comment: Given any sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ converging to $(x_0,y_0)$ there is a path $g$ passing through these points and ending at $(x_0,y_0)$. So there is no counter-example.

Comment: If the infimum is a continuous function of the angle, then it's continuous on a compact set, and therefore must achieve its minimum.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Is that using some fact like if for all $a_n$ convergent to $p$, $f(a_n) $ is convergent to a same value then $f$ is convergent to that value?

Comment: Yes, that is right.

Comment: @RobertShore I didn't get what is meant by angle.

Comment: It might be easiest to prove the contrapositive. Suppose $\lim_{(x,y)\to p}f \ne L$, then for some $\epsilon>0$ there is a sequence $(x_n,y_n)$ converging to $p$ such that $|f(x_n,y_n)-L|>\epsilon$ for all $n$. Then you can construct a path $g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ connecting all these $(x_n,y_n)$, along which you would have $\lim_{t \to 1^-}f(g(t))\ne L$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I see, thank you.

Comment: it depends. What, precisely, does the word "path"   mean here?

Comment: @WillJagy I don't have a precise definition, just used it as it is used in elementary calculus books (e.g. path through origin along the $x$-axis, path through origin along the line $x=y$ etc.) How does that make a difference?

Comment: I assumed you were referring to linear paths through the origin, which can be characterized in polar coordinates via an angle.  If you're talking about arbitrary paths (i.e., paths that could be arbitrarily curved), then the concept of angle doesn't make sense here.

Comment: @RobertShore Oh no I meant any kind of path, straight line, spiral... I think that could be formalized as any continuous $g(t): [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^2$ which passes the point $p$ at some $t_0$. Now is it possible to extend your idea in some way?

Comment: @1Rock yes thank you I got the idea of using sequences.

Comment: if you meant straight lines through the origin, the usual counterexample is $\frac{x y^2}{x^2 + y^4}$

Comment: @WillJagy No I was taking arbitrary paths as I mentioned in my third to the last comment